# Split Flap text animation Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-animate

Can you please suggest me a Jquery plugin which does the same text animation as this demo: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1sn5FCSIfuE&feature=youtu.be

This is the text animation made in Flash (check it out here: http://ae.tutsplus.com/tutorials/motion-graphics/create-a-split-flap-type-display/) but I would like to have the same effect in pure Javascript, CSS and HTML.

Thanks for your advice,
Leo

Answer (score 4):

It's doable with some CSS3 3D Transforms. While it won't work for every browser, it can be done.

Heres a non-css3 version (with less flair and no 3D): http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/learn-how-to-create-a-retro-animated-flip-down-clock/

And here a (few) CSS3 demo: http://rupey.org/demo/css3-clock/, http://mathieujouhet.com/demos/flipping-clock/

Comment: Thanks @Bruno for posting my demo. Though it should be noted that it does only work on Safari now (used to work perfectly in Ffox, Chrome and Opera but it seems the implementation changed since I uploaded the demo).

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution in Javascript:
http://cnanney.com/journal/demo/apple-counter-revisited/

Answer (score 0):

Not 3D - but the same principal:

http://keith-wood.name/flightBoard.html

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure this is what you're looking for, but you can always check out this:

[Textillate.js - A jQuery Plugin For CSS3 Text Animations](http://www.functionn.in/2013/01/textillatejs-jquery-plugin-for-css3.html)

Textillate.js allows you to animate text with effects such as flash, bounce, shake and more easily. I've tried it out and it is pretty awesome and is built upon provided JavaScript libraries.